# How to have differents placeholders with two select2

Tags: jquery-select2

Test on http://jsfiddle.net/7J8Ag/31/.
With :

```
 var opts=$("#select1").html(), opts2="<option></option>"+opts;
 $("select.populate").each(function() { var e=$(this); e.html(e.hasClass("placeholder")?opts2:opts); });
```

I have correctly two differents "placeholders", but the list in #select0 is the same of #select1. So it's not ok.

I don't know, practically, to have two differents "placeholders" in two differents select2.

Comment: I don't understand? What exactly do you want to do?

Comment: I want two differents select2 (with differents placeholders, differents lists, differents actions...) on the same page html. In the test, when I introduce "placeholder" the list of #select0 is not the right list in html select.