# Multiple select2 form-fields with different placeholders in symfony forms

Tags: jquery, symfony, jquery-select2

I am having difficulty creating different placeholders for each form field that work with Select2. My first placeholder is also displayed on any consecutive field, which should have it's own placeholder. A similar question might have been [asked before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21072525/how-to-have-differents-placeholders-with-two-select2), although I do not completely understand that question, nor does it have an answer.

**What I have so far**

On my file `base.html.twig` I included the script of Select2 and have created these few lines of code:

```
<script>
    $('select[data-select="true"]').select2({
        placeholder: $('select[data-select="true"]').attr("data-placeholder")
    });
</script>
```

In my FormType file, in the form builder I have:

```
->add('firstEntity', EntityType::class, [
    'class' => firstEntity::class,
    'multiple' => true,
    'attr' => ['data-select' => 'true', 'data-placeholder' => 'first placeholder'] 
])
->add('secondEntity', EntityType::class, [
    'class' => secondEntity::class,
    'multiple' => true,
    'attr' => ['data-select' => 'true', 'data-placeholder' => 'second placeholder'] 
])
```

The problem is that in a form with two fields like above, the first placeholder is displayed in both fields. So `'first placeholder'` will be the placeholder for both fields instead of both fields having their own.

**My question:** how can I have individual placeholders for each Select2 form field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you're setting the placeholder is incorrect. Here's why:

You have the `data-select` attribute set to both the `select` tags. And as you try to fetch the placeholder text from the data attribute using `$('select[data-select="true"]').attr("data-placeholder")`, it will always give you the first element with the `data-select="true"` set which is why you'll see the same placeholders for both the selects.

Here's a snippet using your approach:

```js
$('select').each(function () {
 $(this).select2({
   placeholder: $('select[data-select="true"]').attr("data-placeholder"),
    allowClear: true
  })
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.6-rc.0/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.6-rc.0/js/select2.min.js"></script>

<p>Select0 >>>base simple
    <br>
    <select style="width:300px" id="select0" class="populate placeholder" data-select="true" data-placeholder="first placeholder">
        <option></option>
        <option value="AK">Alaska</option>
        <option value="HI">Hawaii</option>
    </select>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>Select1 >>> with link
    <br>
    <select style="width:300px" id="select1" class="populate placeholder second" data-select="true" data-placeholder="second placeholder">
        <option></option>
        <option value="IA">Iowa</option>
        <option value="KS">Kansas</option>
        <option value="KY">Kentucky</option>
        <option value="VT">Vermont</option>
        <option value="VA">Virginia</option>
        <option value="WV">West Virginia</option>
    </select>
    <p id="log"></p>
```

To fix this, here's one approach (going through the select individually and then setting the placeholder based on the attribute)

```js
$('select').each(function () {
 $(this).select2({
   placeholder: $(this).data('placeholder') || $(this).attr('data-placeholder'),
    allowClear: true
  })
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.6-rc.0/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.6-rc.0/js/select2.min.js"></script>

<p>Select0 >>>base simple
    <br>
    <select style="width:300px" id="select0" class="populate placeholder" data-select="true" data-placeholder="first placeholder">
        <option></option>
        <option value="AK">Alaska</option>
        <option value="HI">Hawaii</option>
    </select>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>Select1 >>> with link
    <br>
    <select style="width:300px" id="select1" class="populate placeholder second" data-select="true" data-placeholder="second placeholder">
        <option></option>
        <option value="IA">Iowa</option>
        <option value="KS">Kansas</option>
        <option value="KY">Kentucky</option>
        <option value="VT">Vermont</option>
        <option value="VA">Virginia</option>
        <option value="WV">West Virginia</option>
    </select>
    <p id="log"></p>
```

Hope this helps. (Btw I'm using the JSFiddle snippet that you're referring to in the question)

Comment: This was very helpful indeed, thanks. I had to change only a small portion of your code so that not every selectable field would use Select2 in my form (there are more fields). So in the first line I now have `$('select[data-select="true"]').each(function () {` which works well.

Comment: Yep, you got it. Glad I could help.